# Installing MySQLDB for python 2.7 using pip on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7

I have spent hours trying multiple approaches to install MYSQLDB module for python, and no success.

My python version: 2.7.6

Django - 1.10.3

OS: Windows 7 64-bit

MySQL connector - MySQL Connector C 6.0.2

Currently I have an error in my project, namely:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

I have tried to install mysqldb running the following command:

```
pip install mysql-python
```

It ran successfully, but the error still persisted. Then I tried to run

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

and I am getting `Cannot open include file config-win.h`.
I came across this post, but I don't understand the idea of the answer, specifically, I can't figure out where I should look for the mentioned files `site.cfg` and `setup_windows.py`. There are no such files in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include`

Finally, I tried to install MySQLDb using wheels running
`pip install mysqlclient-1.3.9-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` command, I end up with

`mysqlclient-1.3.9-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform` error.

I have lost my hope. Help please !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install 32 bit version mysqlclient-1.3.9-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

If it doesn't work try to install it from (where you can find compiled windows libraries):

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Yes, it works indeed ! But won't it lead to hard to fix errors in the future - I mean running 32-version on 64 machine ?

Comment: Maybe you have 32 bit version of MySQL. Reinstall it and try again, but I'm not sure if you will be able to install mysqlclient-1.3.9-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl after that.